# Any idea how I could make this code more efficient?

Tags: python-3.x

I've just started learning Python and am setting myself the challenge of trying to create practical little programs that do something. I created a dictionary with months of the year and corresponding average temperatures. I ask the user what month they'd like to choose and then display the temperature for that month.

However it seems like I am re-writing a lot of the same code, but just changing the months. Can someone advise alternate, more efficient ways of achieving this?

```py
# This program shows the average temperature for the month you have chosen

dict = {'january': 10, 'february': 10, 'march': 12, 'april': 14, 'may': 18, 'june': 21, 'july': 25, 'august': 25, 'september': 21, 'october': 18, 'november': 14, 'december': 11,}

month = input('When are you visting Majorca? \nChoose month: ')
if month == 'january':
    print ('In january the average temperature will be: ')
    print (dict['january'] , 'degrees celsius')
if month == 'february':
    print ('In february the average temperature will be: ')
    print (dict['february'] , 'degrees celsius')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

```py
dict = {'January': 10, 'February': 10, 'March': 12, 'April': 14, 'May': 18, 'June': 21, 'July': 25, 'August': 25, 'September': 21, 'October': 18, 'November': 14, 'December': 11,}

month = input('When are you visiting Mallorca? \nChoose month: ')
temp = dict.get(month, None)
if temp:
    print('In {} the average temperature will be: {} degrees Celsius'.format(month, temp))
else:
    print("You didn't enter a valid month!")
```

I'd suggest you to read about `dict.get()` method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey) and about string formatting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/string-formatting-vs-format). You could replace `None` with `False`, but the logic would remain the same. Also, notice the capitalization of names of the months and Celsius, and spelling the name of Mallorca ;)

EDIT:

As of Python 3.6 you can use formatted string literals instead of `str.format()`, see the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) for more detail (thanks to @Andy for pointing this out). The print statement in the `if` block would then be:

```
print(f'In {month} the average temperature will be: {temp} degrees Celsius')
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really useful. Your way is so much better. I don't understand it (yet) but will be sure to learn about the things you suggested. Majorca is the British spelling, either way it doesn't really matter as it's just a practice scenario.

Comment: @sandhun note that this uses old-style strings, check out f-strings as well for even cleaner code.

Comment: @sandhun I hate to say it, but if it answered your question you could accept the answer or upvote it:)

Comment: @gst Apologies, have done so now. F strings make things so much easier.